# How to get struct in templated class to take any type of template parameters?

Tags: c++, templates

I got a class A `template<typename T1, typename T2> class A{...};`
Within this class I would like to have a `struct B {
(type of any of the parameters of A) m_type;
}`. So that I could have a B with m_tpye of T1 and a B with m_type of T2. Is this possible?

Comment: Did you try it? Didn't it work for you? If so, what were the errors you got?

Comment: I didn't get it to work, since I had to template the struct with all parameters.

Comment: [Works here](https://ideone.com/gQfZ5f).

Comment: But I don't want B to have two variables of m_type. I would like to have one being either of T1 or T2 or ..

Comment: So how do you actually plan to determine which of the template parameters should be used for `B::m_type`? Another template parameter? What's your actual use case? Sounds like a XY-problem to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a union:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2> class A {
    struct B {
        union {
            T1 t1;
            T2 t2;
        } m_type;
    };
};
```

However, unions have strict restrictions that might not be acceptable in your case, and they are easy to misuse. I recommend using a type-safe `variant` type instead. Unfortunately there is no such type in the standard library yet, so you need to use a third party implementation, or implement it yourself, or try to get the proposal N4542 into the standard.

I also recommend considering whether you actually need to have objects of type `B` that have members of different type.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like the example below can do the job:

```
template<typename... T>
struct B: T... { };

template<typename T1, typename T2>
struct A{
    B<T1,T2> b;
};

struct S1 { };
struct S2 { };

void f1(const S1&) { }
void f2(const S2&) { }

int main() {
    A<S1, S2> a;
    f1(a.b);
    f2(a.b);
}
```

Here `B` inherits from both `S1` and `S2`, so actually it *is* both of them, as requested by the OP.